# Google-api-php-client CsutomSearch get next results

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-custom-search

I have implemented a custom search, and try to get next Page of results :

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("AAAAAAAAAA");
$client->setDeveloperKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$service = new Google_Service_Customsearch($client);
//Do the query
$query = 'a';
$optParams = array(
        'num' => 10,
        'cx' => 'cxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcx'
        );
$results = $service->cse->listCse($query, $optParams);
print_r($results);
```

How get the next sets of results ? The documentation says that num and start should be used, i.e. &num=10&start=21
But I always get 0 results. Even worse : changing the start parameter changes the number of results :

- num=10&start=0 =>  15100 totalResults,
- num=10&start=11 => 7540 totalResults
- num=10&start=31 => 0 totalResults

The resulting URI gives (Of course, I ran the query with the proper key parameter):
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=a&cx=009948471157722620218%3Aqb_f79-w5zg

What am I doing/getting wrong here ? Any help would be much appreciated !